# Build a matching system using a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to build an algorithm to match people with the same interested industry. The more similar industries they have in common, the more likely they will be recommended to each other as friends.

I have tried a little using the nested for loop to resolve it, but it is kinds of complicated. The idea is to count how many times the other person has a similar interested interest. For example, taking Jim as the object, it should count Tony 1 time, Mark 3 times, and Jessie 2 times. Therefore, it will recommend Mark.

```
Interested_industry = {
    'Jim' : ['Technology','Automotive','Education', 'Environment'],
    'Tony': ['Food & Beverage','Automotive','Insurance', 'Tourism'],
    'Mark': ['Technology','Real Estate','Education', 'Environment'],
    'Jessie' : ['Technology','Real Estate','Transportation', 'Environment']
}

def match_friends():
    n_keys = len(Interested_industry.keys())
    for i in range(n_keys):
        n_values = len(Interested_industry.values())
        student =  list(Interested_industry.keys())[i]
    for j in range(n_values):
      for k in range(1, n_keys):
        student2 = list(Interested_industry.keys())[k]
    if  Interested_industry[student][j] in Interested_industry[student2]:
        print(student2)

match_friends()
```

**Updated** Thanks for @martineau suggestion.

```
from itertools import permutations
def match_friends(interest_dict):
    for person1, person2 in permutations(interest_dict.keys(), 2):
        interests1, interests2 = interest_dict[person1], interest_dict[person2]
        common_interests = list(interests1 & interests2)
        print(f'{person1} & {person2}: common interests: '
              f'{len(common_interests)}')

industry_interests = {
    'Jim' : {'Technology','Automotive','Education', 'Environment'},
    'Tony': {'Food & Beverage','Automotive','Insurance', 'Tourism'},
    'Mark': {'Technology','Real Estate','Education', 'Environment'},
    'Jessie' : {'Technology','Real Estate','Transportation', 'Environment'}
}

match_friends(industry_interests)
```

```
Jim & Tony: common interests: 1
Jim & Mark: common interests: 3
Jim & Jessie: common interests: 2
Tony & Jim: common interests: 1
Tony & Mark: common interests: 0
Tony & Jessie: common interests: 0
Mark & Jim: common interests: 3
Mark & Tony: common interests: 0
Mark & Jessie: common interests: 3
Jessie & Jim: common interests: 2
```

Follow-on question:

I adjusted the code to let it show how many common interests they have. If  I want to pick up people with the highest common interest to pair up. How can I filter out that, for instance, for Jim, he should be paired up with Mark; Mark should be paired up with Jim and Jessie. So the return should be like 'Jim paired up with Mark', 'Mark paired up with Jessie'

Comment: You must use a dictionary for this?

Comment: No, if there are other solutions, I would love to try. I just know the dictionary for now haha.

Comment: well, for starters, if you *were* going to iterate through a dictionary, **don't do it this way**" `list(Interested_industry.keys())[i]`. This makes your iteration *quadratic time*. And linear space. Just use `for key in Interested_industry:`...

Comment: python supports set intersection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand everything that you're trying to accomplish, but think the following will help. It uses a dictionary whose values are sets, which allows determining the common interests using the set intersection operator "`&`".

It also passes the dictionary to the `match_friends()` function to avoid using global variables, which is generally considered a poor practice.

```
from itertools import permutations

def match_friends(interest_dict):
    for person1, person2 in permutations(interest_dict.keys(), 2):
        interests1, interests2 = interest_dict[person1], interest_dict[person2]
        common_interests = list(interests1 & interests2)
        print(f'{person1} & {person2}: common interests: '
              f'{common_interests if common_interests else "~"}')

industry_interests = {
    'Jim' : {'Technology','Automotive','Education', 'Environment'},
    'Tony': {'Food & Beverage','Automotive','Insurance', 'Tourism'},
    'Mark': {'Technology','Real Estate','Education', 'Environment'},
    'Jessie' : {'Technology','Real Estate','Transportation', 'Environment'}
}

match_friends(industry_interests)
```

Output:

```
Jim & Tony: common interests: ['Automotive']
Jim & Mark: common interests: ['Technology', 'Education', 'Environment']
Jim & Jessie: common interests: ['Environment', 'Technology']
Tony & Mark: common interests: ~
Tony & Jessie: common interests: ~
Mark & Jessie: common interests: ['Real Estate', 'Environment', 'Technology']
```

Comment: Thank you, it definitely helps. The permutations functions really solve the problem that I am facing. Thank you so much!

Comment: I have a further question in filtering out the return, it would nice if you can take a look, thank you so much.

Comment: Jim: It's probably way too late at this point, but I'll give you a hint on your follow-on question — I would suggest using a [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) container—a dictionary subclass—whose keys were a tuples of pairs of people and the "count" was the number of common interests they shared. The class even has a `most_common()` method to get those keys with the highest number of common interests.